# why is the express server responding with error eventhough everything is correct

Tags: javascript, express, server, postman, backend

I'm new to using express.js and i'm trying to make a simple sign in example server so i made a database object that has a users array of object and each object if the users array has the properties if email and password, the problem is that eventhough i used body-parser to parse the body into a js object, it always responds with error, here is the code

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const database = {
    users: [
        {
            email: 'jacob@gmail.com',
            password: 'somepw'
        },
        {
            email: 'csqfdqsdf@dfjdskf.com',
            password: 'dkjfzqsdiof'
        }
    ]
}


app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.email === database.users[0].email && req.body.password === database.users[0].password) {
        res.json('success')
    } else {
        res.json('error')
    }
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app is listening')
})
```

the request i've sent with postman:

```
{
    "email": "jacob@gmail.com",
    "password": "somepw"
}
```

as you can see the request matches the data in the database and it still responds with error. Hope i could describe the problem well, thanks

Comment: Can you console.log `req.body` and show the way you're sending the payload from Postman ?

Comment: well it is logging an empty object : {}

Comment: can you show me a screenshot from your Postman?

Comment: https://imgur.com/ownCwge

Comment: what's missing is the `content-type` header. You can just click on the text label and switch to JSON, lemme know if that works

Comment: how didn't i notice that, lol thanks dude this helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part was a `content-type` header which is required when POSTing JSON ([link](https://restfulapi.net/content-negotiation/)). It can be easily turned on in Postman:

[image]